# IIS: .htaccess php_flag / php_value alternative?

Tags: php, iis, configuration, .htaccess

For IIS (5.0 or higher), are there alternatives to apache's .htaccess directives php_flag and php_value to set PHP_INI_PERDIR config values?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems that PHP_INI_PERDIR values cannot be modified (only PHP_INI_USER can). Here is the official information from php.net regarding changes of PHP configuration on Windows:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php#configuration.changes.windows

Answer (score 2):

Since PHP 5.3.0, you can use [*.user.ini*](http://php.net/manual/configuration.file.per-user.php) files.

1. Do a [`phpinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/function.phpinfo.php), and find these entries:

   - *user_ini.filename*, and
   - *user_ini.cache_ttl*.

   [image: user_ini entries in phpinfo()]
2. *user_ini.filename* is the name of the per-directory config file. Its value is usually *.user.ini*.
3. Create the file *.user.ini* and put it in the directory you want to config.
4. The format of *.user.ini* is just like *php.ini*. For example, it may contain something like this:

   ```
   ; Override value of upload_max_filesize
   upload_max_filesize = 4M
   ```
5. Run `phpinfo()` again to check that the value has been overridden by your *.user.ini*.

Notes:

1. For performance reasons, the *.user.ini* file is cached, so you may have to wait until the cache expires. The timeout is specified by *user_ini.cache_ttl*. For example, if *user_ini.cache_ttl* is 300, it means that the *.user.ini* file is cached for 300 seconds.
2. The config file name is ***.user.ini***, starting with a dot.
3. This technique works for CGI/FastCGI SAPI only. See [the doc](http://php.net/manual/configuration.file.per-user.php) for details.