# How to prepend a PHP file to every page using web.config?

Tags: php, iis, web-config

I'm moving from a Linux VPS to a Microsoft Server. With my Linux OS, I was using Apache and could utilize .htaccess

In that file, I had this configuration:

```
php_value auto_prepend_file "/inetpub/htdocs/app/tpl/includes/config/config.php"
```

I then ran into the painful realization that .htaccess does not work with IIS, but only Apache. I now know that IIS uses web.config, but I'm sure what would be the equivalent of this in web.config.

I simply want to append a file to every single PHP page. The website doesn't work without having the config appended, as it contains routes to essential methods.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't move the **auto_prepend_file** directive into **php.ini**?

Comment: @DonR Adding it php.ini will then cause it to prepend to every PHP page even if it's on a different website.

Comment: Are [.user.ini](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30135331/1941241) files configured for your IIS installation? Then you can have a .user.ini file in your project that configures the `auto_prepend_file` directive.

Comment: Also there are ways of having IIS use a different **php.ini** for each site, if it comes to that.